# How can I get the "Display pop-up windows while running in the background" permission?

Tags: java, android, permissions, google-play

How can I get the "Display pop-up windows while running in the background" permission in Android studio using Java? I have also tried "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" but it doesn't work. [Please refer to the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAgYW.jpg)

At first, I thought it was not possible programmatically, but I saw some apps over the play store that have this permission granted.

Thanks in advance.